# JSONify array of arrays

Tags: javascript, json

Just looking for some input on best practice.
I have an array containing arrays.  Call it array1.
array1 contains arrays of strings.
What is the cleanest way to JSONify array1 as a string?
Thanks everyone.

**Edited -- I need array1 as a JSON string.

Comment: `JSONify array1` what does it mean?

Comment: To turn an associative array into JSON object

Comment: There is no need to do so. It is already a JSON object

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy — No, it isn't. http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: `JSON.stringify(array)`.

Comment: Being array of array or just array of object doesn't make any difference, `JSON.stringify(obj)` will convert it to JSON string and to convert it back to js object use `JSON.parse(str)`

Comment: Post the json/string/array.  That is why you are getting downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert an object (json) to a string and simply provide the correct object (`arr`).

```
var arr = [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"]];

var arrStr = JSON.stringify(arr); // simply stringify
console.log(arrStr);
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` can handle just about anything.

Comment: @tadman - Except for circular references. (Which don't apply here.)

Answer (score 2):

The same way you change any other basic data structure into JSON in JavaScript. [With `JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```js
var array1 = [ ["a", "b"], ["c", "d"] ];
var json_text = JSON.stringify(array1);
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(json_text));
```

Comment: JSON.stringify takes care of subelements?  Didn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: @ChristianGerlach Before you drive everyone completely nuts, **post your sample data** so we can compare results.

Comment: @ChristianGerlach — Yes, it does.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify will handle subelements
Just being an idiot